# geoserver css categorized marks

Tags: geoserver, style, css

I have trouble categorize my markers by category (boolean in this case) in geoserver using CSS.
I have tried a few different combinations without success.

Simply I want: if true - yellow square, if false - blue

Suggestions?

What I have tried:

```
* {
  mark: symbol('square'), symbol('square');
}

    [exist=true] :nth-mark(1) {
      size: 12px;
      fill: yellow;
      stroke: yellow;
    }

    [exist= false] :nth-mark(2) {
      size: 12px;
      fill: blue;
      stroke: blue;
    }
```

[image]

```
[exist=true] {
  mark: symbol('square');
  size: 12px;
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: yellow;
}

[exist= false] {
  mark: symbol('square');
  size: 12px;
  fill: blue;
  stroke: blue;
}
```

[image]

If I may ask in the same question. 
This is from doc.geoserver, what is usage, column name?

[usage='hospital'] {
  mark: symbol('circle'), symbol('cross');
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS looks much too complex (you are drawing squares on top of squares) and not entirely correct either, try something like:

```
* {
  mark: symbol(square);
  mark-size: 12px;
}

:mark [NAME = 'art' ]{
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: yellow;
}
:mark [NAME = 'stock' ]{
  fill: blue;
  stroke: blue;
}
```

Further examples can be found in the [css cookbook](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/cookbook/index.html).

Comment: Thank you! Was pulling my hair out for this. Was reading up from the cookbook but I must have interpret it wrong. Thanks again!