# GeoServer CSS categorized marks with different size

Tags: geoserver, css

I am doing categorized marks with GeoServer. The color is fine. I use same template of this question: [geoserver css categorized marks](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201122/geoserver-css-categorized-marks?rq=1)  but I can't figure out how to change the size of my points.

This is what I've tried but my points displaying with the same size

```
* {
  mark: symbol(circle);  
}

:mark [total < 500000]{
  mark-size: 2px;
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: yellow;

}
:mark [total >= 500000] [total < 1000000]{
  mark-size: 5px;
  fill: blue;
  stroke: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing styles that apply to the mark automatically (`mark-size`) and style items that must be applied to the mark (`fill`, `stroke`). The second type must be inside a `:mark` block but the first don't. So your style should look something like:

```
* {
  mark: symbol(circle);  

}

[PERSONS < 5e6]{
  mark-size: 20px;
  :mark{
    fill: yellow;
    stroke: yellow;
  }
}
[PERSONS >= 5e6] {
  mark-size: 10px;
  :mark{
    fill: blue;
    stroke: blue;
  }
}
```

giving this map of US States:

[image]